# Determining threshold for features scoring [Random Forest]

Tags: python, machine-learning

Now, I am scoring the features from accelerometer, gravity, and linear acceleration sensor using random forest approach. The scoring results are following below:

```
Out[145]:
[(0.76, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-1,8'),
 (0.753, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-1,16'),
 (0.749, 'tBodyAccJerk-std()-X'),
 (0.748, 'fBodyAcc-std()-X'),
 (0.748, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8'),
 (0.747, 'tBodyAccJerk-mad()-X'),
 (0.747, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-9,16'),
 (0.747, 'fBodyAcc-entropy()-X'),
 (0.745, 'tBodyAccJerk-energy()-X'),
 (0.744, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-1,24'),
 (0.743, 'tBodyAccJerk-entropy()-X'),
 (0.743, 'tBodyAcc-max()-X'),
 (0.743, 'fBodyAccJerk-max()-X'),
 (0.742, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,16'),
 (0.741, 'tBodyAccJerk-iqr()-X'),
 (0.741, 'fBodyAccJerk-std()-X'),
 (0.741, 'fBodyAccJerk-mean()-X'),
 (0.741, 'fBodyAcc-mean()-X'),
 (0.741, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,24'),
 (0.74, 'fBodyAccJerk-energy()-X'),
 (0.739, 'fBodyAccJerk-mad()-X'),
 (0.739, 'fBodyAccJerk-iqr()-X'),
 (0.739, 'fBodyAcc-mad()-X'),
 (0.737, 'tBodyGyroJerk-iqr()-X'),
 (0.737, 'tBodyAcc-std()-X'),
 (0.736, 'fBodyAcc-energy()-X'),
 (0.735, 'tBodyAccJerk-max()-X'),
 (0.734, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-iqr()'),
 (0.734, 'tBodyAcc-iqr()-X'),
 (0.733, 'tBodyGyroJerk-iqr()-Z'),
 (0.733, 'tBodyAccJerk-mad()-Y'),
 (0.733, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-9,16'),
 (0.732, 'tBodyGyro-std()-Y'),
 (0.732, 'tBodyGyro-mad()-Z'),
 (0.732, 'tBodyGyro-mad()-Y'),
 (0.732, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-mean()'),
 (0.732, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-mad()'),
 (0.732, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-entropy()'),
 (0.732, 'tBodyAccJerk-sma()'),
 (0.732, 'fBodyGyro-std()-Y'),
 (0.732, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-1,16.1'),
 (0.732, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-33,40'),
 (0.732, 'fBodyAcc-iqr()-X'),
 (0.731, 'tBodyGyroJerk-energy()-Z'),
 (0.731, 'tBodyAccJerk-min()-X'),
 (0.731, 'tBodyAcc-mad()-X'),
 (0.731, 'tBodyAcc-energy()-X'),
 (0.731, 'fBodyGyro-energy()-Z'),
 (0.731, 'fBodyAccJerk-sma()'),
 (0.73, 'tBodyGyroJerk-mad()-Z'),
 (0.73, 'tBodyGyro-iqr()-Z'),
 (0.73, 'tBodyAccJerk-iqr()-Y'),
 (0.73, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-1,24.1'),
 (0.73, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-iqr()'),
 (0.73, 'fBodyAccJerk-energy()-Y'),
 (0.73, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-1,8.2'),
 (0.73, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-1,16.1'),
 (0.729, 'tBodyAccJerk-entropy()-Y'),
 (0.729, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-mean()'),
 (0.729, 'fBodyAccJerk-entropy()-X'),
 (0.729, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-1,24.1'),
 (0.729, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-17,24'),
 (0.728, 'tBodyGyroJerk-sma()'),
 (0.728, 'tBodyGyro-iqr()-Y'),
 (0.728, 'fBodyGyro-energy()-Y'),
 (0.728, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-9,16.1'),
 (0.728, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-41,48'),
 (0.728, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-1,8.1'),
 (0.727, 'tBodyGyroJerk-mad()-X'),
 (0.727, 'fBodyGyro-mad()-Z'),
 (0.727, 'fBodyAccJerk-std()-Y'),
 (0.727, 'fBodyAccJerk-mad()-Y'),
 (0.727, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-17,24'),
 (0.726, 'tBodyAccJerk-std()-Y'),
 (0.726, 'tBodyAccJerk-energy()-Y'),
 (0.726, 'fBodyGyro-sma()'),
 (0.726, 'fBodyGyro-mean()-Z'),
 (0.726, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-1,24.2'),
 (0.726, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-33,48'),
 (0.726, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-25,48'),
 (0.725, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-entropy()'),
 (0.725, 'tBodyGyroJerk-std()-Z'),
 (0.725, 'tBodyGyroJerk-std()-X'),
 (0.725, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-energy()'),
 (0.725, 'fBodyGyro-mean()-Y'),
 (0.725, 'fBodyGyro-iqr()-Z'),
 (0.725, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-entropy()'),
 (0.725, 'fBodyAccJerk-entropy()-Y'),
 (0.725, 'fBodyAcc-max()-X'),
 (0.724, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-sma()'),
 (0.724, 'tBodyGyroJerk-iqr()-Y'),
 (0.724, 'fBodyGyro-std()-Z'),
 (0.724, 'fBodyGyro-max()-Y'),
 (0.724, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-17,32'),
 (0.724, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-17,32'),
 (0.723, 'tBodyGyroMag-sma()'),
 (0.723, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-sma()'),
 (0.723, 'tBodyAccJerk-mad()-Z'),
 (0.723, 'fBodyGyro-mad()-X'),
 (0.723, 'fBodyAccJerk-mean()-Y'),
 (0.723, 'fBodyAcc-iqr()-Y'),
 (0.722, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-mean()'),
 (0.722, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-9,16.2'),
 (0.722, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-25,32'),
 (0.722, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-17,24.1'),
 (0.721, 'tBodyGyroMag-energy()'),
 (0.721, 'fBodyGyro-entropy()-Z'),
 (0.721, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-17,32.2'),
 (0.721, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-energy()'),
 (0.721, 'fBodyAccJerk-max()-Z'),
 (0.72, 'tGravityAccMag-entropy()'),
 (0.72, 'tBodyGyro-max()-Y'),
 (0.72, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-std()'),
 (0.72, 'fBodyGyro-mad()-Y'),
 (0.72, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-1,8.2'),
 (0.72, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-sma()'),
 (0.72, 'fBodyAccJerk-iqr()-Y'),
 (0.72, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-33,48.1'),
 (0.72, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-17,24.1'),
 (0.719, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-min()'),
 (0.719, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-max()'),
 (0.719, 'tBodyAccJerk-entropy()-Z'),
 (0.719, 'fBodyGyro-energy()-X'),
 (0.719, 'fBodyAccJerk-max()-Y'),
 (0.719, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-49,56'),
 (0.719, 'fBodyAcc-entropy()-Y'),
 (0.718, 'tBodyGyroJerk-entropy()-Z'),
 (0.718, 'tBodyAccJerk-iqr()-Z'),
 (0.718, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-1,8.1'),
 (0.718, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-1,16.2'),
 (0.718, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-sma()'),
 (0.718, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-mad()'),
 (0.718, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-1,24.2'),
 (0.718, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-1,16.2'),
 (0.718, 'fBodyAcc-sma()'),
 (0.718, 'fBodyAcc-iqr()-Z'),
 (0.717, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-energy()'),
 (0.717, 'tBodyGyroJerk-mad()-Y'),
 (0.717, 'tBodyGyro-sma()'),
 (0.717, 'tBodyAccMag-entropy()'),
 (0.717, 'fBodyGyro-mean()-X'),
 (0.717, 'fBodyAcc-mad()-Y'),
 (0.716, 'tBodyGyroJerk-min()-Z'),
 (0.716, 'tBodyGyroJerk-energy()-X'),
 (0.716, 'tBodyGyro-std()-Z'),
 (0.716, 'tBodyAccJerk-std()-Z'),
 (0.716, 'fBodyGyro-entropy()-Y'),
 (0.716, 'fBodyAccJerk-entropy()-Z'),
 (0.716, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-9,16.1'),
 (0.715, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-iqr()'),
 (0.715, 'tBodyGyroJerk-std()-Y'),
 (0.715, 'tBodyGyroJerk-max()-Z'),
 (0.715, 'tBodyAccJerk-min()-Y'),
 (0.715, 'tBodyAcc-min()-Y'),
 (0.715, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-17,24.2'),
 (0.715, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-std()'),
 (0.715, 'fBodyAccJerk-mean()-Z'),
 (0.715, 'fBodyAccJerk-mad()-Z'),
 (0.715, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-25,48.1'),
 (0.715, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-25,32.1'),
 (0.715, 'fBodyAcc-mean()-Y'),
 (0.714, 'tBodyGyroMag-mean()'),
 (0.714, 'tBodyGyroJerk-energy()-Y'),
 (0.714, 'tBodyGyro-iqr()-X'),
 (0.714, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-9,16'),
 (0.714, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-mean()'),
 (0.714, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-entropy()'),
 (0.714, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-entropy()'),
 (0.714, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-33,40.1'),
 (0.713, 'tBodyGyro-energy()-Y'),
 (0.713, 'tBodyAccJerk-energy()-Z'),
 (0.713, 'fBodyGyro-std()-X'),
 (0.713, 'fBodyGyro-iqr()-Y'),
 (0.713, 'fBodyAccMag-entropy()'),
 (0.712, 'tBodyGyro-min()-Z'),
 (0.712, 'tBodyAcc-min()-X'),
 (0.712, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-1,16'),
 (0.712, 'fBodyAccJerk-iqr()-Z'),
 (0.712, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-17,32.2'),
 (0.712, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-17,24.2'),
 (0.712, 'fBodyAcc-mad()-Z'),
 (0.711, 'tGravityAccMag-sma()'),
 (0.711, 'tBodyGyro-std()-X'),
 (0.711, 'tBodyAccJerk-min()-Z'),
 (0.71, 'tBodyGyro-mad()-X'),
 (0.71, 'tBodyAccMag-sma()'),
 (0.71, 'tBodyAcc-sma()'),
 (0.71, 'fBodyAccJerk-std()-Z'),
 (0.71, 'fBodyAcc-energy()-Y'),
 (0.71, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-25,32'),
 (0.71, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-17,32.1'),
 (0.708, 'tBodyGyroJerk-max()-X'),
 (0.708, 'tBodyAcc-energy()-Y'),
 (0.708, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-17,32.1'),
 (0.708, 'fBodyAcc-mean()-Z'),
 (0.708, 'fBodyAcc-entropy()-Z'),
 (0.708, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,16.1'),
 (0.707, 'tBodyGyroJerk-entropy()-X'),
 (0.707, 'tBodyAcc-std()-Y'),
 (0.707, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-17,24'),
 (0.707, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-1,24'),
 (0.707, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-mad()'),
 (0.707, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-9,16.2'),
 (0.707, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-49,64'),
 (0.707, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-33,48'),
 (0.707, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,24.1'),
 (0.706, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-mad()'),
 (0.706, 'tBodyGyroJerk-entropy()-Y'),
 (0.706, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-min()'),
 (0.706, 'tBodyAccJerk-max()-Y'),
 (0.706, 'tBodyAcc-std()-Z'),
 (0.706, 'tBodyAcc-mad()-Y'),
 (0.706, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-iqr()'),
 (0.706, 'fBodyAccJerk-energy()-Z'),
 (0.706, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-41,48.1'),
 (0.705, 'tGravityAccMag-mean()'),
 (0.705, 'fBodyGyro-iqr()-X'),
 (0.705, 'fBodyGyro-entropy()-X'),
 (0.705, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-25,48.2'),
 (0.705, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-25,48.1'),
 (0.705, 'fBodyAcc-std()-Y'),
 (0.704, 'tBodyAccMag-mean()'),
 (0.704, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-max()'),
 (0.704, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-25,48.2'),
 (0.704, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-25,48.1'),
 (0.703, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-25,48'),
 (0.702, 'tGravityAccMag-max()'),
 (0.702, 'tBodyGyroMag-max()'),
 (0.702, 'tBodyGyro-energy()-X'),
 (0.702, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-17,32'),
 (0.702, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-33,40'),
 (0.702, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-25,32.1'),
 (0.702, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-17,32.2'),
 (0.701, 'tBodyAccMag-max()'),
 (0.701, 'tBodyAccJerk-max()-Z'),
 (0.701, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-33,48.1'),
 (0.701, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-mean()'),
 (0.701, 'fBodyAccMag-iqr()'),
 (0.7, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-17,24.1'),
 (0.7, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-iqr()'),
 (0.7, 'fBodyAcc-energy()-Z'),
 (0.7, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-17,24.2'),
 (0.699, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-9,16.1'),
 (0.699, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-mad()'),
 (0.699, 'fBodyAccMag-mad()'),
 (0.699, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-49,56.1'),
 (0.698, 'tBodyGyroJerk-min()-Y'),
 (0.698, 'tBodyGyroJerk-max()-Y'),
 (0.698, 'tBodyAccMag-energy()'),
 (0.698, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-17,32.1'),
 (0.698, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-sma()'),
 (0.698, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-49,64.1'),
 (0.698, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-33,40.1'),
 (0.697, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-max()'),
 (0.697, 'fBodyGyro-max()-Z'),
 (0.697, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-1,8'),
 (0.697, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8.2'),
 (0.696, 'tBodyGyroJerk-min()-X'),
 (0.696, 'tBodyGyro-min()-Y'),
 (0.696, 'tBodyAcc-mad()-Z'),
 (0.696, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-41,48'),
 (0.696, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8.1'),
 (0.696, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,24.2'),
 (0.696, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,16.2'),
 (0.695, 'tGravityAccMag-energy()'),
 (0.695, 'tBodyGyroMag-std()'),
 (0.695, 'tBodyAcc-min()-Z'),
 (0.695, 'tBodyAcc-iqr()-Z'),
 (0.695, 'fBodyAccMag-mean()'),
 (0.695, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-9,16.2'),
 (0.694, 'tBodyAccMag-std()'),
 (0.694, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-energy()'),
 (0.694, 'fBodyAccMag-sma()'),
 (0.694, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-33,48.2'),
 (0.693, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-33,48'),
 (0.693, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-33,40.2'),
 (0.693, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-25,48.2'),
 (0.692, 'tBodyGyroMag-iqr()'),
 (0.692, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-25,32.2'),
 (0.692, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-33,48.1'),
 (0.691, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-49,56.2'),
 (0.691, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-41,48.2'),
 (0.691, 'fBodyAcc-max()-Y'),
 (0.69, 'tGravityAccMag-std()'),
 (0.69, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-25,32.2'),
 (0.69, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-49,64.2'),
 (0.69, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-41,48.1'),
 (0.69, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-25,32.2'),
 (0.689, 'tBodyAccMag-iqr()'),
 (0.689, 'tBodyAcc-max()-Y'),
 (0.688, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-std()'),
 (0.688, 'tBodyAcc-iqr()-Y'),
 (0.688, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-33,48.2'),
 (0.688, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-25,32.1'),
 (0.688, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-std()'),
 (0.687, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-33,40.1'),
 (0.687, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-25,32'),
 (0.687, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-33,48.2'),
 (0.686, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-25,48'),
 (0.686, 'fBodyAccMag-energy()'),
 (0.685, 'tBodyAccMag-min()'),
 (0.684, 'tBodyGyroMag-mad()'),
 (0.684, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-41,48.1'),
 (0.684, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-energy()'),
 (0.683, 'tBodyAcc-max()-Z'),
 (0.683, 'fBodyGyro-max()-X'),
 (0.681, 'tBodyGyro-max()-Z'),
 (0.681, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-41,48'),
 (0.681, 'fBodyAcc-std()-Z'),
 (0.681, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-33,40.2'),
 (0.68, 'tBodyAcc-energy()-Z'),
 (0.68, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-33,40.2'),
 (0.68, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-33,40'),
 (0.68, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-49,56'),
 (0.679, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-max()'),
 (0.678, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-std()'),
 (0.678, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-49,64'),
 (0.677, 'tGravityAccMag-iqr()'),
 (0.677, 'fBodyAccMag-std()'),
 (0.676, 'tGravityAccMag-min()'),
 (0.676, 'tBodyAccMag-mad()'),
 (0.676, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-49,64.1'),
 (0.675, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-41,48.2'),
 (0.674, 'tGravityAccMag-mad()'),
 (0.673, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-41,48.2'),
 (0.668, 'tBodyGyro-energy()-Z'),
 (0.667, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-49,56.1'),
 (0.666, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-49,56.1'),
 (0.665, 'tGravityAcc-min()-X'),
 (0.662, 'tBodyAcc-entropy()-Y'),
 (0.66, 'fBodyAcc-max()-Z'),
 (0.659, 'fBodyAccMag-max()'),
 (0.653, 'fBodyAcc-maxInds-X'),
 (0.649, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-49,64.1'),
 (0.645, 'tBodyGyro-min()-X'),
 (0.641, 'tGravityAcc-energy()-X'),
 (0.639, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-49,56'),
 (0.638, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-49,64'),
 (0.636, 'tGravityAcc-mean()-X'),
 (0.633, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-49,56.2'),
 (0.63, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-min()'),
 (0.63, 'angle(X,gravityMean)'),
 (0.628, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-max()'),
 (0.627, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-49,56.2'),
 (0.624, 'tBodyGyro-max()-X'),
 (0.624, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-49,64.2'),
 (0.617, 'tGravityAcc-max()-X'),
 (0.607, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-57,64'),
 (0.606, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-49,64.2'),
 (0.599, 'tBodyGyroMag-min()'),
 (0.599, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-min()'),
 (0.58, 'fBodyAccJerk-min()-X'),
 (0.574, 'tBodyAcc-entropy()-Z'),
 (0.573, 'tBodyAcc-entropy()-X'),
 (0.571, 'angle(Y,gravityMean)'),
 (0.568, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-57,64.1'),
 (0.555, 'tGravityAcc-mean()-Y'),
 (0.552, 'tGravityAcc-max()-Y'),
 (0.551, 'tGravityAcc-min()-Y'),
 (0.546, 'fBodyAccJerk-min()-Y'),
 (0.543, 'fBodyAcc-min()-X'),
 (0.533, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-57,64.2'),
 (0.529, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-57,64'),
 (0.522, 'tGravityAcc-energy()-Y'),
 (0.517, 'tBodyGyro-entropy()-Z'),
 (0.504, 'tBodyAccJerk-mean()-X'),
 (0.5, 'fBodyAccJerk-min()-Z'),
 (0.493, 'fBodyAccMag-min()'),
 (0.492, 'fBodyGyro-min()-Y'),
 (0.492, 'fBodyAcc-min()-Y'),
 (0.485, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-57,64.1'),
 (0.485, 'angle(Z,gravityMean)'),
 (0.475, 'tGravityAcc-max()-Z'),
 (0.475, 'fBodyAccJerk-meanFreq()-X'),
 (0.474, 'tGravityAcc-mean()-Z'),
 (0.473, 'tGravityAcc-min()-Z'),
 (0.468, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-57,64.1'),
 (0.466, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-57,64.2'),
 (0.462, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-Z,2'),
 (0.459, 'tBodyGyroJerk-mean()-X'),
 (0.459, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-X,1'),
 (0.458, 'tBodyGyroJerk-mean()-Y'),
 (0.456, 'fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-57,64'),
 (0.449, 'tBodyAccJerk-mean()-Y'),
 (0.445, 'fBodyGyro-min()-X'),
 (0.444, 'fBodyAcc-maxInds-Z'),
 (0.443, 'tBodyGyroJerk-mean()-Z'),
 (0.443, 'fBodyGyro-min()-Z'),
 (0.442, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-min()'),
 (0.435, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-maxInds'),
 (0.435, 'fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-57,64.2'),
 (0.428, 'fBodyAcc-min()-Z'),
 (0.423, 'tGravityAcc-energy()-Z'),
 (0.422, 'fBodyAcc-maxInds-Y'),
 (0.418, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-Z,1'),
 (0.412, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-X,1'),
 (0.407, 'fBodyAccMag-maxInds'),
 (0.403, 'tBodyAccJerk-mean()-Z'),
 (0.388, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-Z,1'),
 (0.366, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-maxInds'),
 (0.363, 'tBodyGyro-mean()-X'),
 (0.36, 'fBodyAccJerk-meanFreq()-Y'),
 (0.342, 'fBodyAccJerk-meanFreq()-Z'),
 (0.336, 'fBodyAccJerk-maxInds-X'),
 (0.333, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-Z,1'),
 (0.326, 'tGravityAcc-mad()-Y'),
 (0.326, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-Y,1'),
 (0.323, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-Y,1'),
 (0.322, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-Z,2'),
 (0.321, 'tBodyGyro-entropy()-Y'),
 (0.319, 'tGravityAcc-std()-Z'),
 (0.317, 'angle(tBodyGyroMean,gravityMean)'),
 (0.315, 'tGravityAcc-mad()-Z'),
 (0.315, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-Z,1'),
 (0.313, 'tGravityAcc-std()-Y'),
 (0.308, 'fBodyGyro-maxInds-Y'),
 (0.296, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-Z,3'),
 (0.285, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-arCoeff()1'),
 (0.282, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-Z,2'),
 (0.277, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-Y,2'),
 (0.276, 'fBodyAccJerk-skewness()-X'),
 (0.275, 'tBodyAcc-correlation()-X,Y'),
 (0.272, 'fBodyGyro-maxInds-Z'),
 (0.27, 'tGravityAcc-iqr()-Z'),
 (0.268, 'tBodyAcc-mean()-X'),
 (0.266, 'tGravityAcc-iqr()-Y'),
 (0.26, 'tBodyGyro-mean()-Y'),
 (0.258, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-X,2'),
 (0.256, 'tBodyGyro-mean()-Z'),
 (0.247, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-arCoeff()2'),
 (0.242, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-X,2'),
 (0.239, 'tBodyGyroMag-entropy()'),
 (0.237, 'fBodyAccJerk-skewness()-Y'),
 (0.236, 'fBodyAcc-skewness()-X'),
 (0.233, 'tBodyAcc-mean()-Y'),
 (0.231, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-maxInds'),
 (0.227, 'fBodyAcc-kurtosis()-X'),
 (0.225, 'angle(tBodyAccMean,gravity)'),
 (0.221, 'tGravityAcc-std()-X'),
 (0.219, 'tBodyGyro-entropy()-X'),
 (0.217, 'fBodyAccJerk-kurtosis()-X'),
 (0.215, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-skewness()'),
 (0.214, 'tGravityAcc-mad()-X'),
 (0.213, 'tBodyAcc-correlation()-Y,Z'),
 (0.211, 'tBodyAcc-mean()-Z'),
 (0.207, 'tGravityAcc-entropy()-Y'),
 (0.207, 'tGravityAcc-correlation()-Y,Z'),
 (0.201, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-kurtosis()'),
 (0.198, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-Y,1'),
 (0.196, 'fBodyBodyAccJerkMag-meanFreq()'),
 (0.192, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-Y,2'),
 (0.192, 'angle(tBodyAccJerkMean),gravityMean)'),
 (0.19, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-X,4'),
 (0.187, 'tGravityAccMag-arCoeff()1'),
 (0.187, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-X,1'),
 (0.183, 'tGravityAccMag-arCoeff()2'),
 (0.182, 'tGravityAcc-iqr()-X'),
 (0.182, 'tBodyAccMag-arCoeff()2'),
 (0.179, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-X,1'),
 (0.176, 'fBodyAcc-meanFreq()-X'),
 (0.175, 'tBodyAccMag-arCoeff()1'),
 (0.171, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-X,3'),
 (0.169, 'fBodyAccJerk-skewness()-Z'),
 (0.161, 'fBodyAccMag-skewness()'),
 (0.157, 'fBodyAccJerk-kurtosis()-Y'),
 (0.156, 'fBodyAcc-skewness()-Y'),
 (0.15, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-X,2'),
 (0.143, 'tGravityAcc-entropy()-Z'),
 (0.141, 'tBodyGyro-correlation()-Y,Z'),
 (0.139, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-X,2'),
 (0.136, 'fBodyAccMag-kurtosis()'),
 (0.132, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-Z,3'),
 (0.13, 'fBodyAcc-kurtosis()-Y'),
 (0.129, 'fBodyAccMag-meanFreq()'),
 (0.129, 'fBodyAccJerk-kurtosis()-Z'),
 (0.128, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-Y,1'),
 (0.127, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-X,1'),
 (0.126, 'fBodyAccJerk-maxInds-Z'),
 (0.119, 'tGravityAcc-correlation()-X,Z'),
 (0.116, 'tGravityAcc-entropy()-X'),
 (0.115, 'tGravityAccMag-arCoeff()3'),
 (0.115, 'fBodyGyro-maxInds-X'),
 (0.113, 'tGravityAccMag-arCoeff()4'),
 (0.108, 'tBodyAccMag-arCoeff()3'),
 (0.108, 'fBodyGyro-meanFreq()-Z'),
 (0.101, 'tGravityAcc-sma()'),
 (0.101, 'tBodyGyro-correlation()-X,Y'),
 (0.1, 'tGravityAcc-correlation()-X,Y'),
 (0.1, 'tBodyAccMag-arCoeff()4'),
 (0.098, 'tBodyAccJerk-correlation()-Y,Z'),
 (0.096, 'tBodyGyro-correlation()-X,Z'),
 (0.096, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-X,3'),
 (0.096, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-meanFreq()'),
 (0.092, 'fBodyAccJerk-maxInds-Y'),
 (0.092, 'fBodyAcc-meanFreq()-Y'),
 (0.088, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-X,3'),
 (0.087, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-Y,4'),
 (0.082, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-arCoeff()2'),
 (0.082, 'fBodyAcc-skewness()-Z'),
 (0.081, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-Y,3'),
 (0.078, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-arCoeff()1'),
 (0.077, 'fBodyAcc-meanFreq()-Z'),
 (0.073, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-Z,4'),
 (0.073, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-X,4'),
 (0.072, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-Z,4'),
 (0.07, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-Y,2'),
 (0.068, 'tBodyAccJerk-correlation()-X,Y'),
 (0.068, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-Z,3'),
 (0.067, 'fBodyAcc-kurtosis()-Z'),
 (0.065, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-Y,1'),
 (0.064, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-Y,2'),
 (0.063, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-X,4'),
 (0.061, 'tBodyAcc-correlation()-X,Z'),
 (0.06, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-Z,4'),
 (0.058, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-Z,4'),
 (0.058, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-skewness()'),
 (0.056, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-Z,3'),
 (0.055, 'tBodyGyroJerk-correlation()-X,Y'),
 (0.054, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-Z,2'),
 (0.054, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-X,4'),
 (0.053, 'tBodyAccJerk-correlation()-X,Z'),
 (0.051, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-Y,3'),
 (0.048, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-Z,3'),
 (0.045, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-kurtosis()'),
 (0.042, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-Z,2'),
 (0.042, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-Y,2'),
 (0.039, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-Y,3'),
 (0.036, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-Y,4'),
 (0.034, 'tGravityAcc-arCoeff()-Z,1'),
 (0.031, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-Y,3'),
 (0.029, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-Y,4'),
 (0.029, 'fBodyBodyGyroMag-meanFreq()'),
 (0.029, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-skewness()'),
 (0.028, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-arCoeff()4'),
 (0.027, 'fBodyGyro-meanFreq()-X'),
 (0.024, 'tBodyGyroMag-arCoeff()4'),
 (0.024, 'fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-kurtosis()'),
 (0.023, 'fBodyGyro-skewness()-X'),
 (0.022, 'tBodyGyro-arCoeff()-X,3'),
 (0.02, 'fBodyGyro-skewness()-Y'),
 (0.019, 'fBodyGyro-kurtosis()-X'),
 (0.015, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-X,2'),
 (0.014, 'tBodyAccJerk-arCoeff()-Y,3'),
 (0.014, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-Z,4'),
 (0.014, 'fBodyGyro-skewness()-Z'),
 (0.014, 'angle(tBodyGyroJerkMean,gravityMean)'),
 (0.011, 'tBodyGyroJerk-correlation()-X,Z'),
 (0.01, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-arCoeff()3'),
 (0.01, 'tBodyGyroJerk-correlation()-Y,Z'),
 (0.01, 'fBodyGyro-kurtosis()-Y'),
 (0.009, 'tBodyAccJerkMag-arCoeff()3'),
 (0.009, 'fBodyGyro-kurtosis()-Z'),
 (0.007, 'tBodyGyroMag-arCoeff()3'),
 (0.007, 'tBodyAcc-arCoeff()-Y,4'),
 (0.005, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-X,4'),
 (0.005, 'fBodyGyro-meanFreq()-Y'),
 (0.004, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-Y,4'),
 (0.002, 'tBodyGyroJerk-arCoeff()-X,3'),
 (0.001, 'tBodyGyroJerkMag-arCoeff()4'),
 (-0.0, 'tBodyGyroMag-arCoeff()1'),
 (-0.001, 'tBodyGyroMag-arCoeff()2')]
```

In here, I want to ask how to determine which the features that give significant influence to classification results based on their score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - you cannot. This just gives you ordering, now you can trim them and check on some validation set - how it increases (or does not) generalization capabilities.

Comment: So it means that we can not determine something such as threshold etc?